# How to make Logback complete compression before my short-lived application exits?

Tags: logging, logback

I'm using the `rollingPolicy` in Logback to gzip the logs. However, as my application is short-lived (run and quit immediately), it randomly can't finish compressing the log file, resulting in some `.tmp` files. Is there any way to have Logback prevent my application from exiting until compression completes? I've tried to simply switch to `AsyncAppender` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Logback `v1.1.3` you can add a `ShutdownHook` into your configuration. This will instruct Logback to shut itself down gracefully, including completing any in-flight work such as compressing files on rollover.

In XML configuration you add a `ShutdownHook` by including the following in your `logback.xml`:

```
<shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>
```

Alternatively, you can be explicit about your desired delay period (in milliseconds) as follows:

```
<shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook">
    <delay>100</delay>
</shutdownHook>
```

More details [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHook). Note: the docs incorrectly imply that you do not need to supply a shutdown hook classname. However, you do have to supply a class name (there's an [open issue](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1090) to get the docs fixed).